# Identity server 4 and redirect after login

Tags: react-native, identityserver4

We have a react application that now uses deep linking. Eg http://<my-fully-qualified-domain#my-custom-page

Now when the react app makes a call to the api it gets a challenge and is redirect to identity server for a token.

All works great.
Now the use of the deep linking means users can favourite a section of the application.

If their token has expired, they get redirected. When they login, they don’t get returned to the page that they favourites. Instead it’s the home page.

Any idea? Do I need to somehow save the url on the client and intercept the login success? And redirect? Seems like a bad UX.